# How to separate title area color from background color in fancytikzposter

Tags: tikzposter

I am using Elena Botoeva's `fancytikzposter` package and I'd like to combine the blue wave-shaped head from template N5 with a plain white background. However, since the heading and the background share the same color gradient, I can only get a white background with a grayscale heading "wave" (with `\setbackgrounddarkcolor{white}`), or a heading of a specified color and a background that is a lighter shade of that color. Is there any easy way to separate the color of the title area from the color of the rest of the background, without having to create a new background image from scratch?

I thought I could solve this by setting `bottom color=backgroundlightcolor,` instead of the default `bottom color=backgrounddarkcolor!55!backgroundlightcolor,` in the corresponding .sty file, but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Edit (thanks, JMP!): The "minimum working example" below actually only works with the fancytikzposter.sty file, which can be downloaded [here](http://www.inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/tikz/fancytikzposter_sources.zip).

```
\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage{fancytikzposter} 
\usetemplate{5}
\usecolortemplate{3}

\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{008888} 
\setfirstcolor{myblue}
\setbackgrounddarkcolor{myblue} % If set to white, the background will be white and the title area gray.
\setbackgroundlightcolor{white} % This makes the background a lighter shade of myblue rather than white.
%% I'd like to have the title area in myblue, with everything below white.

\title{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\author{Lorem Ipsum \and Dolor Sit Amet\\
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt\\
  \texttt{lorem.ipsum@dolor.sit}
 }

\begin{document}

\ClearShipoutPicture
\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \initializesizeandshifts

  \ifthenelse{\equal{\template}{1}}{ 
    \titleblock{75}{1}
  }{
    \titleblock{75}{1.5}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please help us to help you and provide a minimal working example containing fully compilable code, illustrating your problem, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Did you see this comment on the [fancytikzposter homepage](http://www.inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/fancytikzposter.html): _NOTE that we joined our efforts with the tikzposter team, which resulted in an improved version 2.0 of the tikzposter class that you can find in http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter. This class combines both good structure and nice layouts. The official webpage of our project is https://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter/wiki/ (under construction)._

**I am not going to maintain this style.**

Probably it is a good idea to switch to tikzposter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first like to say, as JMP did in the comment, that as the maintainer of `fancytikzposter` recommends moving to the `tikzposter` class, that should be considered. And what you want to do, if I understand you correctly, is fairly easy in that case.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{tikzposter}
\usetheme{Wave}
\title{Whatnot}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{008888} 
\colorlet{titlebgcolor}{myblue}
\colorlet{blocktitlebgcolor}{myblue!80!black}
\colorlet{backgroundcolor}{white}
\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{blue!5} %default is white
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\block{Some words}{Bla bla}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But if you don't want to let go of `fancytikzposter`, you can quite easily do it by editing `fancytikzposter.sty`. In lines 455-458, right after where it says `%%%%% template N5` you will find

```
        \draw[draw=none, %
        bottom color=backgrounddarkcolor!55!backgroundlightcolor, %
        top color=backgrounddarkcolor!35!backgroundlightcolor ] %
        (bottomleft) rectangle (topright);
```

This is what draws the background for the template you have chosen (`\usetemplate{5}`). If you change those lines to

```
        \draw[draw=none, %
        fill=white] %
        (bottomleft) rectangle (topright);
```

your example code will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, works for template 4 as well in the old fancytikzposter.